# add luasocket to program (bizhawk) shipped with own lua environment

Tags: lua, luasocket, lua-5.1

I am trying to get luasocket working in the lua scripting environment of [Bizhawk](http://tasvideos.org/BizHawk.html), but so far without luck. I downloaded the vc8 version of luasocket [here](http://files.luaforge.net/releases/luasocket/luasocket/luasocket-2.0.2), made sure I have vc8 installed, and checked the lua version that came with bizhawk: 5.1

But, when I start the script I get the following error:

```
LuaInterface.LuaScriptException: error loading module 'socket.core' from file './libs/socket\core.dll':
    Das angegebene Modul wurde nicht gefunden. (the given module was not found)
```

The lua code:

```
package.path = package.path..';./libs/lua/?.lua'
package.cpath = package.cpath..';./libs/?.dll'
local socket = require("socket")
```

The file system structure:

```
libs
   > lua
       > socket
            ftp.lua http.lua smtp.lua tp.lua url.lua
       ltn12.lua
       mime.lua
       socket.lua
   > socket
       core.dll
   > mime
       core.dll
```

It seems to find the files, because when I had the file structure wrong it gave me actual file-not-found errors.
My best guess is that there is some kind if incompatibility between the lua that is shipped with Bizhawk and the external luasocket library binaries, but I am out of ideas.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This guy's set it up: https://github.com/antogerva/emuHostUDP (dearchive to emuhawk.exe base directory). His example seems to work, but it might not contain everything you need. Like HTTP for example.

Since project is complex and the luasockets examples are awful, here's a one-liner for testing http:

```
print(require("socket.http").request{ url = "http://www.google.com" });
```

Following his model, I applied the following method: contents of lua dir to root; lua5.1.dll to root. Note that we will not be using the core.dlls from luasockets. This is because *BizHawk now has them integrated; and this was necessary to work around a bug with luasockets in bizhawk.*

More specifically, we have

- /emuhawk.exe
- /Lua (untouched)
- /Socket/ftp.lua,http.lua,etc.
- /ltn12.lua,socket.lua,mime.lua
- /lua5.1.dll
- /mytest.lua

(with files from http://files.luaforge.net/releases/luasocket/luasocket/luasocket-2.0.2/luasocket-2.0.2-lua-5.1.2-Win32-vc8.zip)

I can't say why precisely all of this is necessary, but I think it's miraculous that it works, given that we have a *customized* lua.

When using lua, if you find a directory structure that works, it's best not to wrestle with it any further.

**Update**:
*(may be out of date)* As soon as you do something nontrivial you may find bizhawk crashes. It seems this is due to a conflict with luasocket's "protection" system. Inspect http.lua and observe the code at the end which sends a function through `socket.protect` to wrap it. Remove the `socket.protect` wrapper and it should solve this problem.

Comment: I gave this another shot because our old build of VBA is slowly falling apart, and your setup does work. However, you said bizhawk has luasockets baked in now. It doesn't seem so, or I don't know how to access it.

Comment: 1. OK, it was broken. I studied it further and updated post with my findings.

Comment: Alright, thanks so much for helping me with this. It's a shame that this lua situation is so messy, but I am glad that it works somehow.

Comment: Nevermind. Turns out bizhawk crashes if a http request can't establish a connection, even with the `socket.protect` wrapper removed

Comment: I have to correct myself again. It doesn't _even_ crash then, it crashes _only_ if i modify the lua file to remove the protect wrapper.

Comment: I have determined this is because the built-elsewhere luasockets uses exception handling code incompatible with our hacked lua and possibly .net. Therefore I've made a branch including my homemade luasockets for you to try out at https://github.com/zeromus/BizHawk/tree/luasockets. You will still need the lua files from luasockets, but not the dlls. I dont know if you need to hack the http.lua (I think not, though)

If this works out for you guys then we edit the answer to say "you MUST not use built-elsewhere luasockets; use an updated bizhawk's built-in luasockets"

Comment: I have used it quite a bit now and it seems to run perfectly stable. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

I suspect that it's because of the dependence on lua51.dll. luasocket `core.dll` library is linked against `lua51.dll` (most likely; you can ran `depends` or similar tool to find out for sure), which is probably not present and this prevents `socket.core` from being loaded.

Even if you find `lua51.dll`, it's not likely to work if Bizhawk is statically compiled with `lua51.dll` as this will lead to two interpreters loaded into the same process, which is a recipe for seg faults.

There are three main options, but they all depend on how Bizhawk project is structured:

1. Bizhawk is compiled against `lua51.dll` (and this dll is present as a standalone file). In this case you need to make sure that the `socket/core.dll` you are using is compiled against the same library and it should work (as long as the run-times are the same and `lua51.sll` is available in `PATH`).
2. Bizhawk is statically compiled with `lua51.dll`. The simplest option is also statically compile luasocket libraries into the executable.
3. If option 2 is not available, then you need to use a proxy library and export Lua symbols from the Bizhawk executable as described in this SO answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/28310666/1442917

If none of this helps you to solve the problem, you'll need to get `depends` for your Windows platform and run it in the "profiling" mode, which will tell you the exact error that happens when that DLL is loaded.